# IOS Simulator shows black screen whenever I open it from Xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native, ios-simulator, apple-m1

I am a React Native Developer. Few months ago I shifted to Macbook. I installed Xcode and IOS Simulator worked fine. But then I stopped using Xcode as I was not working on React Native. But recently I had to develop an application on React Native but when I started IOS Simulator it just shows black screen.
Details about my Macbook:
It is a Macbook Pro Mid 2015, MacOS version **(Monterey 12.6.4)**
My Xcode version **14.2** [My IOS Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/128x8.png)

Following solutions I implemented but no luck

1. I restarted my Macbook
2. I reinstalled Xcode
3. I reinstalled Command Line Tools
4. I Erased all Content and Settings from Simulator->Device
5. I restarted my Simulator
6. I even deleted Xcode Caches and Project Build Data and Indexes from About this Mac->Storage-> Manage-> Developer
7. I also ran following command in my terminal
   `> sudo xcrun simctl erase all`
   `> xcrun simctl shutdown all`

Comment: Does the simulator display nothing when 'Home' button is pressed? Or just black screen when running your RN code?

Comment: Just black screen when launched. Nothing happens if home button is pressed